# mysql on duplicate key update the entire row

Tags: mysql, java

### this is a jsp code

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement("select ssn,name,gender,bod,address,profession,phone from contacts ");
        ResultSet rss = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while(rss.next()){
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO contacts (id,ssn,name,gender,dob,address,profession,phone) VALUES (default,'" +rss.getString(1) + "','"+rss.getString(2) + "','"+rss.getString(3)+"','" +rss.getString(4) + "','"+rss.getString(5) +"','"+rss.getString(6)+"','"+rss.getString(7)+"' on duplicate key update ssn=VALUES("+rss.getString(1)+")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
            out.println("<tr style='background-color:white'>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(1));out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(2));out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(3));out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(4));out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(5));out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(6));out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td>");        out.println(rss.getString(7));out.println("</td>");         
out.println("</tr>");
                            }
```

---

### *out put:*

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on duplicate key update ssn=VALUES(1)' at line 1**

*note:* Server version: 5.7.10-log MySQL Community Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used:

```
INSERT INTO contacts 
    (id, ssn, name, gender, dob, address, profession, phone) 
VALUES 
    (default, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ssn = VALUES(1) ;
```

where `1, 2, 3, ..` are the values passed form the application (check your method by the way, seems like it's vulnerable to SQL injection)

The error you get is because `VALUES(1)` is not valid syntax. The last line should be either:

```
    ssn = 1 ;               -- the value , repeated
```

or:

```
    ssn = VALUES(ssn) ;     -- reference to the value that was 
                            -- to be inserted to column "ssn"
```

Comment: Simplify that by removing `id,` and `default,`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a query inside a loop, think about whether you can do the looping in SQL with a *single* query; that is, not really a loop.

```
INSERT INTO contacts 
             (ssn, name, gender, dob, address, profession, phone) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        ssn = VALUES(ssn),
        name = VALUES(name),
        ...
    SELECT ssn, name, gender, dob, address, profession, phone
        FROM ...
```

or, simply

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO contacts (ssn, ...)
    SELECT ssn, ... FROM ...
```

But...  This does not make sense.  You are reading all the rows of `contacts` and inserting them back into the *same* table?  What did you mean to do?

I am assuming that `ssn` is a `UNIQUE` key; otherwise `IODKU` may not work.

Note that `id` does not need to be specified in any of the variants; assuming it is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY`.  However, why have `id`?  Just use `SSN` as the PK.

You need some serious security consulting -- If your machine is hacked into, the SSNs could expose you to serious legal consequences.